# downloading mysql-server and now my terminal is red

Tags: 16.04, mysql, gnome-terminal

When I start downloading MySQL from my terminal using the command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

my terminal goes all red, and I don't know what to do.

I answered yes and then the screen goes red and if I hit enter it will go away but i won't see the screen to enter a new password for MySQL-server.

And sorry I'm still new at this

See the picture

[image: Red screen in Terminal]

Comment: I think your screenshot would have been more helpful if it at least also contained the window borders and title bar, not just a solid red rectangle. So the whole terminal window is red, and there is no shell prompt or any other text? What happens if you hit Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D?

Comment: I'll take another screenshot and try to upload it

Comment: I uploaded the new screenshot, is that what you meant?

Comment: how does this happens? when you hit the enter ? when you answer "yes" to installation?

Comment: As I understand it happens while installing? is that right? e.g: while mysql setup asks you for password and other configurations ...

Comment: Right after I said yes the screen went red and it's been red all this time. And yes while installing but it never asked me for the password or any other configuration

Comment: Have you tried installing anything else? what if you install a simple app: `sudo apt-get install axel` or what if you install mysql using `apt`: `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: So it goes red immediately after you type `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and hit enter? Or does it show any messages before that? And again, what happens if you hit Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D while it is red?

Comment: @Ravexina it only happens when I use sudo apt-get install mysql-server, I could try installing using apt instead of apt-get

Comment: @ByteCommander after I say yes, and nothing happens if hit Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D while it's red

Comment: It looks like something got screwed up with the default debconf frontend - you could try reverting to a commandline frontend using `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: @steeldriver and what will that do?

Comment: @JuanCarlos Can you check other terminals like `xterm` too?

Comment: It will do exactly the same as your original command, only it will present the configuration questions inline in the terminal (instead of popping up an ncurses-based dialog box)

Comment: @steeldriver I tried to do it with your command but it still didn't work

Comment: @Ravexina I opened xterm and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the cause of problem. However if you want to install `mysql-server` you can simply use another terminal like `xterm` which should be installed by default or other ones like: `xfce4-terminal`, `terminator`, etc.

The other solution might be using other utilities for software installation things like: `apt`, `aptitude`, etc.

You can also try to reconfigure the `gnome-terminal` that might be helpful:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-terminal.
```

Comment: I think this is a very poor answer and hence I downvoted. There's no proof this is a bug in `gnome-terminal`. It could be, although pretty unlikely. Still, in that case chances are `xfce4-terminal`, `terminator` etc. suffer from the same problem. In the unlikely case of this being caused by a `gnome-terminal` bug, the chances of a `dpkg-reconfigure` fixing it is even more unlikely.

Comment: @egmont In my opinion OP wants to install the `mysql-server`, we first worked on it and after he was happy by installing it; I sent it as an answer ;) Also I didn't mentioned anywhere that it's a bug instead I mentioned that I'm not aware of the cause of the problem.